# How is this expansion of $2^{ab} - 1$ obtained?

Tags: prime-numbers, proof-explanation

Can anyone help me to understand this proof (From Richard Hammack's Book of Proof Ch. 5)?:

If $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and $2^n-1$ is prime, then $n$ is prime.

Proof. Assume $n$ is not prime. Write $n=ab$ for some $a, b > 1$. Then $2^n-1 = 2^{ab}-1 = (2^b-1)(2^{ab-b} + 2^{ab-2b} + 2^{ab-3b} + \ldots + 2^{ab-ab})$. Hence $2^n-1$ is composite.

I don't understand the expansion of $2^{ab}-1$ into all those terms. Is there some theorem being applied there?

Comment: Try working backwards. Distribute the $2^b-1$ into the $2^{ab-b}+2^{ab-2b}+\ldots+2^{ab-ab}$ and see what you get.

Comment: $\frac{2^{ab}−1}{2^b−1}$ is formula for sum of a geometric progression.

Comment: @MichaelMorrow thanks, I tried that and sure enough it does make sense - the first term is $2^{ab}$ and the last term is $-2^0$, and all the other terms in between are cancelled, to give $2^{ab}-1$. But I was wondering if there is some general rule that allows one to expand a term in the original form like this. It kinds of reminds me of the binomial theorem - is there something of that kind that he's applying here?

Comment: They are using the rule described in Tortar's answer. It's one of those "known facts" about certain polynomial expressions.

Answer (score 4):

Use

$$x^n - y^n = (x - y)(x^{n - 1} + x^{n - 2} y + \cdots + x y^{n - 2} + y^{n - 1})$$

with $x = 2^b,y = 1, n = a$.

Answer (score 0):

They use $$2^{ab}-1=(2^b)^a-1=p^a-1$$ and the well-known factorization of $$p^a-1.$$